CSS: Help! Need help with icon centering in Divi
I hope someone can help me with this. Been struggling for a few days now. Last resort is to do this manually.
Screenshot below is how my site icons are now. I'm using Divi and this one is a Divi Supreme icon list module. I've tried all sorts of adjustments but I can't get the icon to center-align with the text below.

Current CSS:
selector span.dsm_icon_list_icon {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
}
selector span.dsm_icon_list_wrapper {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
}
selector span.dsm_icon_list_text {
  display: block;
  margin-top: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}

Here's how the html code looks like now:

Hope someone can help me. Please! 
